# How do I delete this or that row in python?

Tags: python, pandas

`one.dropna(subset = ['director', 'cast'])`

When I use this I delete both rows, but I want to delete either director or cast rows that are NaNs, how do I do that?

Comment: What should be the output of the following example: `one = pd.DataFrame({'director': ['v1', 'v2', pd.NA, pd.NA], 'cast': ['v3', pd.NA, 'v4', pd.NA]})`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

`one.dropna(subset = ['director', 'cast'], how = 'any')`

You need to add `how` parameter inside the dropna function. It can be either 'any' or 'all'.

Comment: Care to add a bit of commentary (or doc link) for this and future readers who do not know about the `how` parameter?